# Fetch data return Untheorized 401 access to asp.net core API protected in Azure AD

Tags: api, azure-active-directory, bearer-token, blazor-webassembly

Im new to `webassembly blazor, Im spend too much time trying to figure out what's wrong here but I couldnt manage.

I have the following scenario:

1. Asp.net API registered and protected in Azure AD
2. Expose API with Scope `AcessApi` with status `enabled`
3. A Client application is added to `authorized client applications`
4. Token configuration both are checked Access Token and ID Token

And a client app that will call the API, developed in `webassembly blazor`

1. client app is registered in Azure AD
2. Client API permissions has delegated permission to use my client API
   with correct scope `AccessApi`.

I tested the API using swagger interface, it forces user to authenticate first before accessing the API.
I tested using `curl` and grabbed the token from swagger interface and works perfectly fine.

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9400/api/getdata" -H  "accept: text/plain" -H  "Authorization: Bearer XX"
```

However, when my client application trying to access the API, a sign-in page pop-up for credentials, I could see the Token ID at browser bar being retrieved and while calling the API the app logs error `not authorized`

program class of the client application:

```
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");
            //builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);


            ////builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
            builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("AccessApi",
               client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9400"))
              .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
                .CreateClient("AccessApi"));

           builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
               builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(scope);
            });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
```

in `CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler` class I have defined:

```
 private static string scope = @"api://xxx-35fc2470889f/AccessApi";

        public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider,
            NavigationManager navigationManager)
            : base(provider, navigationManager)
        {
            ConfigureHandler(
            authorizedUrls: new[] { "http://localhost:9400" },
        }
```

In `appsettings.json` a defined the client id of the API and tenant id without scopes since they are been defined in the `CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler`class:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>",
    "ClientId": "<clientid>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ValidateAuthority": "true"
  }
}
```

After a successful login via Azure AD, I call to fetch data from the API here

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
...
try
                {
                    responseBody = await Http.GetStringAsync("/api/getdata"); # use base URL of the API 
                                  }
                catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException ex)

                {
                    ex.Redirect();
                }
}
```

the console logs

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[1]
      Authorization was successful.
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.AccessApi.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET http://localhost:9400/api/getdata
:9400/customer-manager/api/getdata:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

What could be wrong here?
Is there a way how to print the return token?

*Update*

I tested the API using Postman where auth Grant type is `Implicit`, after successful login, I store token on variable and passed in the header as `Bearer` the API return `401` Unauthroized. I decoded the token it contains the right scope `AccessApi` , with the correct clientId. what could be wrong here ?

Comment: It was a lot of code to consume, do you have a repo?
The rest api, is it Azure Functions? I just wonder if you miss out the scopes.
And, since you say you are new to this, my best advice is to study the responses in the browser. I am not saying it will solve this problem, but it is surprising how often problems can be solved there.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you project your web API?

Comment: @RaymondA on the browser  I could see an Id Token being return in where in tabhost where we insert urls. I grabbed that token and decode it doesnt not contains scope. maybe this the problem?

Comment: @jimxu what do you mean ?

Comment: @ikenahim I want to know how you integrate azure ad with API application?

Comment: My Api is registered and configured in Azure AD, 3 roles are defined and assigned to users, users are added to the API application, and one scope is exposed `AccessApi`, the client app is added to trusted app to call my api. is this what you mean @jimXu

Comment: @ikenahim Thanks for your information. please check my answer.

Comment: @ikenahim  You should decode the `access token` instead of the `id token`. The id token only contains the information of the logged-in user, not the scope.

Comment: @JimXu what is the api client you mentioned here ? `await apiClient.GetStringAsync("path");` 
`

Comment: @ikenahim Sorry. I made a mistake. It is `httpClient`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call Microsoft graph and your custom API in one blazor webassembly project, we can implement it by creating different HTTP client to call different API

For example

- **Register a server API app**

  1. Register an AAD app for the Server API app
  2. [Expose an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis#add-a-scope)
- **Register a client app**

  1. Register a client app
  2. [Enable Implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-spa#enable-the-implicit-flow)
  3. Add API permissions. ( API app permissions)
- **Configure API app**

Please add the following code in `Startup.cs`

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
        services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod());
            });
               services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority += "/v2.0";


                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    
                    ValidIssuers = new[] {
                      $"https://sts.windows.net/{Configuration["AzureAD:TenantId"]}/",
                      $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AzureAD:TenantId"]}/v2.0"

                    },
                    RoleClaimType = "roles",
                    // The web API accepts as audiences both the Client ID (options.Audience) and api://{ClientID}.
                    ValidAudiences = new[]
                    {
                           options.Audience,
                           $"api://{options.Audience}"
                    }

                };

            });
....
}
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.OAuthClientId(Configuration["Swagger:ClientId"]);
                c.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
                c.OAuthAppName("Protected Api");

                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

- **Configure Client APP**

1. Create custom AuthorizationMessageHandler for Graph API and custom API

```
// custom API
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;

public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider,
        NavigationManager navigationManager)
        : base(provider, navigationManager)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(
            authorizedUrls: new[] { "<your web API url>" },
            scopes: new[] { "the API app scope" });
    }
}
```

2. Add the following code to the program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
           
            // register HTTP client to call our own api
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("<your web API url>"))
              .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
           
  
            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("<the API app scope>");
                
            });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }
```

3. Call the api

```
@inject IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory

var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient("<the client name you register>");
await apiClient.GetStringAsync("path");
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is almost like mine I updated mine, after I sign-in I got this error when I call my api `crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property 'Http' on type 'CustomerApplication.Pages.BatchPage'. There is no registered service of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'Http' on type '.CustomerApplication.Pages.BatchPage'. There is no registered service of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'`

Comment: `Batchpage` is where I fetch data from the API

Comment: @ikenahim  I use `IHttpClientFactory` to crete httpclient. For more details, please refer to IHttpClientFactory

Comment: Im also using IHttpClientFactory  interface to create Httpclient but that doesnt seem right.

Comment: @ikenahim have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0#named-httpclient-with-ihttpclientfactory

Comment: The right way to declare : `var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("ServerAPI");
                    responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync("api/path");`

Comment: After testing same problem `the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`.

Comment: you answer didnt help actually. I have almost the same implementation therefore i wont accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue was on the server side ASP.net core where I was validating the token in `ConfigureServices` at `startup` class:

```
 // For token parameters validation
            services
            .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.Audience = "<xx>"; // Application id 
                o.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<xx>"; // Tenant ID 
                //Token validation
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false, ValidateIssuer = false, ValidateAudience = false, ValidateLifetime = true};

            });
```

I had to disable Issuer since the token is coming from a different application.